Aspose API for Java and Python
I'm trying to read the mduration function through Apache POI and it does not support that it seems.
While exploring options for extracting the mduration formula result from excel, I came across this Aspose library.
I want to know if this freely available and how this can be used in Java or python program extract the mduration result in our program.
A code snippet elaborating the same would be much appreciated.
Need details about Aspose cells API and how to use the same in Java and Python programs.

A search engine search trivially finds: https://reference.aspose.com/cells/java/ which very likely answers HOW TO and HOW MUCH

Generally, Aspose.Cells is a commercial component which is not available for free although Aspose provides free trial versions that come with certain limitations allowing users to explore its capabilities before making a purchase. You can download and utilize Aspose.Cells for both Java and Python libraries.
Aspose.Cells is a feature-rich and robust library designed for programmatic manipulation of all Excel file formats and rendering features.Moreover, it can perform complex calculations, including advanced Excel formulas like the MDURATION (Modified Duration) function, all without requiring Microsoft Excel to be installed on your system.
I will write two examples (one with Aspose.Cells for Java and other with  Aspose.Cells for Python SDK) to demonstrate on setting and calculating MDURATION formula/function in Excel spreadsheet for your needs.
[Java]
//Instantiating a new Workbook
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

//Get the first worksheet (default worksheet) in the workbook
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);

//Insert values into cells for MDURATION formula calculation
worksheet.getCells().get("A1").putValue("Setting date");
worksheet.getCells().get("A2").putValue("01-Mar-2018");
worksheet.getCells().get("B1").putValue("Maturity Date");
worksheet.getCells().get("B2").putValue("01-Mar-2028");
worksheet.getCells().get("C1").putValue("C Rate");
worksheet.getCells().get("C2").putValue(0.04);
worksheet.getCells().get("D1").putValue("Yield");
worksheet.getCells().get("D2").putValue(0.05);
worksheet.getCells().get("E1").putValue("freq.");
worksheet.getCells().get("E2").putValue(2);

//Set MDURATION formula in the cell
worksheet.getCells().get("F1").putValue("MDURATION function result");
worksheet.getCells().get("F2").setFormula("=MDURATION(A2, B2, C2, D2, E2)");

//Calculate the results for the formula(s)
workbook.calculateFormula();

// Get the calculated result from the cell
double mdurationResult = worksheet.getCells().get("F2").getDoubleValue();

//Printing the result
System.out.println("MDuration result: " + mdurationResult);

//Save the output Excel file to disk
workbook.save("d:\\files\\output_mduration_results1.xlsx")


MDuration result: 8.054231061185153

[Python]
import jpype
import asposecells

# Start JVM
jpype.startJVM()

# Import Aspose.Cells for Python
from asposecells.api import Workbook

# Instantiating a new Workbook
workbook = Workbook()

# Get the first worksheet (default worksheet) in the workbook
worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0)

# Insert values into cells for MDURATION formula calculation
worksheet.getCells().get("A1").putValue("Setting date")
worksheet.getCells().get("A2").putValue("01-Mar-2018")
worksheet.getCells().get("B1").putValue("Maturity Date")
worksheet.getCells().get("B2").putValue("01-Mar-2028")
worksheet.getCells().get("C1").putValue("C Rate")
worksheet.getCells().get("C2").putValue(0.04)
worksheet.getCells().get("D1").putValue("Yield")
worksheet.getCells().get("D2").putValue(0.05)
worksheet.getCells().get("E1").putValue("freq.")
worksheet.getCells().get("E2").putValue(2)

# Set MDURATION formula in the cell
worksheet.getCells().get("F1").putValue("MDURATION function result")
worksheet.getCells().get("F2").setFormula("=MDURATION(A2, B2, C2, D2, E2)")

# Calculate the results for the formula(s)
workbook.calculateFormula()

# Get the calculated result from the cell
mdurationResult = worksheet.getCells().get("F2").getDoubleValue()

# Printing the result
print(f"MDuration result: {mdurationResult}")

# Save the output Excel file to disk
workbook.save("d:\\files\\output_mduration_results1.xlsx")

# Shutdown JVM
jpype.shutdownJVM()


MDuration result: 8.054231061185153

Hope this helps a bit. Also, you may post your queries in the dedicated forum.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Hello Amjad... Very grateful for this information...this really helps...I had one more question... My code has to be imemented in a distributed environment... Hence performance is very critical... You mentioned that excel is not required to be installed...so the calculations are done in-memory...?

Yes, calculations would be done in the memory by Aspose.Cells APIs. Please note, Aspose.Cells has its own and independent formula calculation engine which can calculate MS Excel formulas/functions in Excel spreadsheets efficiently and dynamically and give you results at runtime.
